# Performance of average/group by [Postgres]

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization

New(ish) to postgres, trying to improve performance on a query:

```
SELECT avg(calendar.price)
FROM calendar
INNER JOIN listings ON calendar.listing_id = listings.id
WHERE listings.city = 'London'
GROUP BY calendar.date;
```

listings is ~150k rows, calendar is ~30 million. The query takes 20 seconds to execute,.

I have separate indexes on listings.id, listings.city, calendar.listing_id and calendar.date.

Can this be optimised?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: "I need to do this faster so I can switch between cities." -- you could select and group by city also.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on calendar.city and make sure that listing_id and calendar.id are the same data type. If the are not, cast them to the same type in your query.

If you do an query explain and copy the result of the query planner to https://explain.depesz.com/ you can get better understanding of where the bottleneck might be.

Answer (score 0):

Composite BTree indexes for:

```
listings:  (city, id)
calendar:  (listing_id, date, price)
```